# spring boot - Can I read json files placed in src/main/resources by environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project with json files placed by environment under `src/main/resources` like this:
`src/main/resources/dataFiles/dev` - contains dev json files
`src/main/resources/dataFiles/local` - contains local json files, and so on.

I am trying to read the json file path depending on the active environment. 
i.e. vaguely speaking, something like : 
`String path = "dataFiles/${spring.profiles.active}/someFile.json"`

1. Is there a way to do this using spring profiles? How to ?
2. If I were to do this in an efficient way, what would it be ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes you can do this.  In your component that you are doing the read, inject `Environment`

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

Then get the profiles with

```
String [] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
```

Keep in mind that many profiles may be active, so this returns an array.  If you are certain that you will only set a single active profile, then you can the get the file as

```
String path = "dataFiles/" + activeProfiles[0] + "/someFile.json";
```

Probably a better approach would be to create property file for each of your profiles ad place the data path in the profile.  e.g. for the local profile, create a application-local.yml file, and put a property in there called something like datapath, set to `"datafiles/local/"`.  In your component that reads the file, then you just have to inject this property

```
@Value("${datapath}")
String dataPath;
```

The read your file like

```
String path = dataPath + "someFile.json";
```

Comment: @srinivasreddyramaram you're welcome, if this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted.